# JNDI lookup issue in WildFly - 9.0.2 Final for accessing JMS hornetq via spring JMS listener with connection factory

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jndi, hornetq, wildfly-9

I am configuring JNDI look parameters for getting connection factory to consume messages using Spring JMS listener from web application.

It is throwing below error,

```
"No connection Provider avilable for http-remoting"
```

And we are using below parameters,

```
jms.jndiTemplate.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:8080
jms.jndiTemplate.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
jms.connectionFactory.jndiName=jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
```

But it is working fine for standalone client with above parameter and is throwing error when deployed using web application on the same server.

Even I tried with JNP client,

```
jms.jndiTemplate.provider.url=hostname:1099
jms.jndiTemplate.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
```

And I end up with server port issues as mentioned below,

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.client] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0190: Step handler org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1@30a0f455 for operation {"address" => [("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),("socket-binding" => "iiop")],"operation" => "add","interface" => "unsecure","port" => 3528,"fixed-port" => undefined,"multicast-address" => undefined,"multicast-port" => undefined,"client-mappings" => undefined} at address [
    ("socket-binding-group" => "standard-sockets"),
    ("socket-binding" => "iiop")
] failed handling operation rollback -- java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

Could you please provide the information If I miss anything.

Comment: When you are using WildFly 9 and thus Java EE version 7, is there something which prevents you from making use of the JMS 2.0 annotation features instead of trying to configure it like done above? If not, check out [Java EE tutorial on JMS examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jms-examples005.htm#BABBABFC).

Comment: @Alexander, We have configured our web application to listen to any of the JMS jndi queues that are configured in spring artifact such that on Message() (using  ..springframework.jms.listener.SessionAwareMessageListener,DefaultMessageListenerContainer) can listen to any of the queues.And we have single class that acts as listener to process any ofthe messages with in the queues. As part of this setup we are maintaining properties file for passing JNDI parameters to 'connectionFactory' bean.  Please let me know If I can make use of this setup or suggest me If there is other way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, if it's an established artifact, you may have to do it that way, can't say from here if you'd be better off otherwise. I didn't recognize the Spring tag in your question, I fear I can't help here very much.